# why Java Pair shows android.util.Pair instead of values

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add `Pair list` to my android project, but when I call it back it gives me this value instead of the pair `android.util.Pair`.

Here is how I create and call it :

```
List<Pair<String, String>> StationList = new ArrayList<>();

..................
double Lat = "Some latitude"
double lon = "Some logitude"
Pair StationLatLong = new Pair(lat, lon);
StationList.add(StationLatLong);Log.d("Station List", String.valueOf(StationList));
```

And here is how the output looks like:

[image: LogCat]

Comment: Because of the [Pair.toString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html#toString()) implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get each value within the Pair

```
stationList.first;
stationList.second;
```

Comment: If this was the correct answer first, then mark it as so. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

`String::valueOf` calls `Object::toString` on object passed to it. `StationList` is list of `android.util.Pair` and undernetath it uses `android.util.Pair::toString` which is not overriden and documented in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair).

You can try to create your own class which extends `android.util.pair` and overrides `toString` :

```
class MyPair<T, W> extends Pair<T, W> {
    public MyPair(T first, W second) {
        super(first, second);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPair{" +
                "first=" + this.first +
                ", second=" + this.second +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the Pair class and override its `toString()` method so that it prints what you need. Then use your own class instead of `android.util.Pair`.

Answer (score 0):

All of those answers helped me to find out the right method to do it :

```
for (Pair<String, String> SingleItem : StationList) {
   Log.d("Latitude", String.valueOf(SingleItem.first));
   Log.d("Longitude", String.valueOf(SingleItem.second));
                    }
```

By looping through the List, and showing every part of the pair using `.first` and `.second`